# download zip files from php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want my code to download MySQL files from a table that has a download button.

```
<tr>

  <td>Id</td>
  <td>Numero de Solicitud</td>
  <td>Nombre y Apellido</td>
  <td>Cédula</td>
  <td>Tipo de Solicitud</td>
  <td>Fecha</td>
  <td>Documents</td>
  <td>Estatus</td>
  <td>Cambio de Estatus</td>
   
  </tr>
```

I have a simple table header where it brings me all the user information in the documents part which is the download button. I want my code to download the folders according to their ID, since all the saved files are saved with the user ID number.

```
// Get real path for our folder
$rootPath = realpath('c:/xampp/htdocs/issv/upload/26908557');

// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('26908557'), ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object

$zip->close();

//Download the zip file
$file=file("c:/xampp/htdocs/issv/upload/26908557.zip");
$file1= implode("", $file);
header("Content-Type: appliation/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=26908557.zip");
echo $file1;
```

So far I can only get the file I am going to download to convert it to a zip file and download it, how can I get users to download it?

Comment: So...where is the download button you're talking about? It probably needs to be part of a form which has a hidden field containing the user ID of the user whose records you want to download. (Or it could be a link which looks like a button, which passes the user ID in the URL parameters when it's clicked). Then the PHP can read the ID of the selected user, and only search for folders with that ID to put into the zip. Does that help? It was a bit unclear exactly where you're stuck with this, and what you've researched or tried so far.

Comment: You can use readfile https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.readfile.php to pass the file to the browser. The headers in the first comment on that page are required so the browser knows that you want it to download.

Comment: I fixed my problem now I have another one and that is to be able to download the zip files by ID number.

Comment: That goes back to my first comment I think.

Comment: yes exactly but I already fixed one of my problems

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? And how is this related to MySQL?